# ignoring @ when reading from text file

Tags: c

I have the following text file

```
@1234
5,4
@tfxc
01AAX
11AA1
@tfxc
11AA1
11111
```

And I want to ignore the @ and the data behind it when reading from the text file and the 5,4 are the dimensions of the matrix which I am storing in a 2d array.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *inp;

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int y = 0; 
    int x = 0; 
    char comma;
    char arr = 0;

    inp = fopen("App.txt", "r");

    fscanf(inp, "%d", &x); 
    fscanf(inp, "%c", &comma);
    fscanf(inp, "%d", &y);

    char array[y][x];

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {   
            fscanf(inp, "%c", &arr);

            if ((arr == '1') || (arr == 'X') || (arr == '0') || (arr == 'A')) {
                array[i][j] = arr;
            } else {                           
                j--;
            }
            printf("%c", arr);
        }
    }
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: `buff` seems to be undeclared ;)

Comment: "How..?" Read line by line, if the first symbol =='@' then do not save this line.

Comment: how can you not save the line ? if(buff=='@')
                        {
                            what do you write here ?
                        }

Comment: I'll write (if buff will be the first symbol of string): `if(buff != '@') { ..save to array... } `

Comment: what about what is after the @, i did as u said and it skips the first letter or number of the line below it

Comment: but since the first two numbers are the size of the matrix, how can i ignore the first @ if at the begining im trying to read the x, the middle @'s i managed to ignore the begining @'s i dont know

Comment: Why 5x4? Your data are 6x5. And it should be `(i = 0; i < x; i++)`, `i` would run from 0 to 5 inclusive. `(j = 0; j < y; j++)`, `j` would run from 0 to 4 inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets()` to read lines, check if the line should be ignored, else parse the line to initialize your matrix.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, i, j, k, x = 0, y = 0;
    char line[1024];
    FILE *inp;

    inp = fopen("App.txt", "r");
    if (inp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open App.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        if (line[0] == '@') continue;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d,%d", &x, &y) == 2)
            break;
        printf("invalid line: %s", line);
        exit(1);
    }

    char array[y][x];

    for (i = 0; i < y;) {
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, inp)) {
            printf("missing matrix data at row %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
        if (line[0] == '@')
            continue;
        for (j = k = 0; j < x && line[k] != '\0'; k++) {
            c = line[k];
            if (c == '1' || c == 'X' || c == '0' || c == 'A') {
                array[i][j] = c;
                j++;
                putchar(c);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
        if (j != x) {
            printf("missing matrix values at %d,%d\n", i, j);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(inp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @katie21: Can you please click the grey check mark below to answer score to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int y = 0, x = 0;

    FILE *inp = fopen("App.txt", "r");
    if(!inp){
        perror("fopen\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(2 != fscanf(inp, "%d,%d", &x, &y)){
        int ch;
        while((ch=fgetc(inp)) != '\n' && ch !=EOF);//skip
        if(ch == EOF){
            fprintf(stderr, "There is no dimension specified.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    char array[y][x];
    char format[32];
    sprintf(format, "%%%d[01AX]%%c", x);

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        int status;
        char newline = 0, buff[x+1];
        status = fscanf(inp, format, buff, &newline);
        if(status == 0 || status == 2 && newline != '\n'){//status 1 is OK
            int ch;
            while((ch=fgetc(inp)) != '\n' && ch !=EOF);//skip

            --i;
            continue;
        }
        if(status == EOF){
            fprintf(stderr, "Necessary data is missing.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy(array[i], buff, x);
    }
    fclose(inp);
    //check print
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            putchar(array[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```